# calculating rotation delta based off initial angle and current angle

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm looking to track the rotation delta (y axis) between two readings.

There's a game object that I read an initial angle from when it starts moving.
Then I have another variable that reads the live angle during the update loop.

<del>I want the delta value to be agnostic of whether it's negative or positive, essentially I'm going to apply the same updates whether the object rotation 20 degrees to the left or right.</del>

EDIT:
I want the delta value to be the smallest angle, so the maximum it could be is 180, before counting back down to 0.

EXAMPLE:
If my initFaceAngle == 5 and currentFaceAngle == 355 then myAngle == 10

```
void Start()
{
    initFaceAngle = hmd.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
}
void update()
{    
    currentFaceAngle = hmd.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
    // My terrible first attempt... look ma' I can math.
    float myAngle = (float)Math.Abs(initFaceAngle - currentFaceAngle);
}
```

Obviously my calculation won't work because getting the difference between two angles doesn't take into account the 360 degree. So I figured I need some pie (pi) on this, but outside of being an impressive pie (pi) eater I don't have a clue how to invoke its magical math powers.

What formula do I need to use to capture the delta?

How can I make it read the same whether rotating left or right?

Comment: You can use modular arithmetic (360 degrees).  A number greater than 180 degrees will be a negative rotation.

Comment: I'm somewhat unclear on why the difference wouldn't work for you. If your angle changes by 20 degrees, then Math.Abs should work for you, regardless of direction. If you're concerned with an angle that rotates 380 degrees, then you can do `var myAngleDelta = Math.Abs((initFaceAngle - currentFaceAngle) % 360)`.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I don't want myAngle to count up to 359 and then jump to 0 I want it to calculate the smallest angle, so the highest myAngle can be would be 180.
So I suppose my question is: How do I calculate the smallest angle delta between initFaceAngle and currentFaceAngle?

Answer (score 2):

Because you only want the angle between the initial and current position, it's actually no math involved, only a simple check to see which value is the greatest.

```
void update()
{    
    currentFaceAngle = hmd.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
    float myAngle;
    if(initFaceAngle > currentFaceAngle)
        myAngle = initFaceAngle - currentFaceAngle;
    else
        myAngle = currentFaceAngle - initFaceAngle;

    if(myAngle > 180)
        myAngle = 360 - myangle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've worked out a solution, not sure if it's the most graceful but the output values look correct.

```
void Start()
{
    initFaceAngle = hmd.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
}
void update()
{    
    currentFaceAngle = hmd.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y;
    float myAngle = getDeltaAngle(initFaceAngle, currentFaceAngle);
}

public static float getDeltaAngle(float a, float b)
{
    float x;
    float y;


    if (a > b)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
    else
    {
        x = b;
        y = a;
    }

    if (x - y < 180)
    {
        x = x - y;
    }
    else
    {
        x = (360 - x) + y;
    }

    return x;
}
```